# How to implement scroll-then-fix items in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have a problem but I don't know what keyword should I use to indicate this issue.. so I named it scroll-then-fix.

What I want to do is make element behave as below

1. It scrolls up and down with other contents
2. When scrolling up, when it reaches the top of the screen, it does not go up anymore and stays at the top, while other contents continuously scrolls up.

For example, when you click any app in app store, the segmented control in the middle act like this.

I have no idea and I don't know what keyword I should search in google to find any information (I don't even know what this is called).

Please help me or give me a hint.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I would do that effect from the app store is that I would have a `UITableView` with 2 sections. The first would contain no section header and only one cell (containing the app icon, app name and "GET" button), and the second section would have a section header (containing the segmented control) which will stick to the upper side of the screen. The second section cells would contain the app screenshots, description etc.

Answer (score 1):

Plain style `UITableView's` header behaves like that. Try it.